# string and var concatenation as jquery selector isn't working. Possible reason is closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm tweaking [bootstrap-tabcollapse.js plugin](https://github.com/flatlogic/bootstrap-tabcollapse). To the original method, in the js file, I've added bootstrap accordion listener `show.bs.collapse` to the panel:

```
   TabCollapse.prototype._createAccordionGroup = function(parentId, $heading){
        var tabSelector = $heading.attr('data-target'),
            active = $heading.data('bs.tabcollapse.parentLi').is('.active');

        if (!tabSelector) {
            tabSelector = $heading.attr('href');
            tabSelector = tabSelector && tabSelector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, ''); //strip for ie7
        }

        var $tabPane = $(tabSelector),
            groupId = $tabPane.attr('id') + '-collapse',
            $panel = $(this.options.accordionTemplate($heading, groupId, parentId, active));
        $panel.find('.panel-heading > .panel-title').append(this._tabHeadingToPanelHeading($heading, groupId, parentId, active));
        $panel.find('.panel-body').append($tabPane.contents().detach())
            .data('bs.tabcollapse.tabpane', $tabPane);
     $("#"+groupId).on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
         console.log("show");
        });
        return $panel;
    };
```

Lines added:

```
 $("#"+groupId).on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
             console.log("show");
            });
```

I smell closure problem, but can't quite put my finger on it. So where is it?

Comment: do you know what is the value of groupId? is there any console error?

Comment: no there isn't any console error. Yes I logged, it is non-null value. If I hard code the value instead of groupId, it works

Comment: can you typically log something for `$('#'+groupId)`? If so, it might be that the event isn't triggering as you'd expect.

Comment: have you tried assigning hard coded value to `groupId` variable and then try? I think there is some invalid character in variable , try to trim it and then use.

Comment: I dont find any problems in the code.... here is bare example: https://jsfiddle.net/t9pmq3sz/

Comment: Yes I have. It was unsuccessful.

Comment: You might want to try run the plugin yourself with my 3 lines added in the necessary place.

Comment: _createAccordionGroup method is inside a loop. Im aware about the  loop closure problem. May be it is the problem?

Comment: what are you actually trying to do with the tweak.... ? Like when the tab-accordian is shown/opened, then console log it??

Comment: I'll change style of the panel-header. But that's besides the point. The question is why I'm not getting the log

Comment: So basically you are trying to detect if the panel is opened or closed right?? The reason you are not getting the log is because, that event is not mapped or triggered for those divs with those ids/classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason why it isn't working might be because, the custom event isnt mapped to those elements or the event triggering is not happening correctly (actual reason not known).

But from looking at the code, comments and what you are trying to achieve(to my understanding), is, to do something when you are opening a accordion tab. So I think you can achieve that by using the API given, instead of tweaking it. A simple code would be like this :

```
$(document).on("shown.bs.collapse",".panel-collapse",function(e){
   $(".panel-heading").css({"background-color": ""});
   $(e.currentTarget).closest(".panel").find(".panel-heading").css({"background-color":"red"});
 });
```

Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/t9pmq3sz/1/

**Update:**

I experimented with the tweak and managed to get it working somehow, instead of directly using the `$("#"+groupId)`, Im using it like this:

```
$(document).on("shown.bs.collapse","#"+groupId,function(e){
  console.log(e);
});
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/t9pmq3sz/3/

Hope it helps

Comment: The first reason that I can come up with is that it is `shown.bs.collapse` and not `show.bs.collapse`. And I think `$("#"+groupId)` might work with the above event. Just test it out and see if it works.